# Is there any way to show a countdown on the lockscreen of iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

The integral countdown has a limit of 24 hours, but I want a countdown which could count for a few years. It could show the time like `XXXXDays XXHours XXminutes XXseconds` with large characters on the lock screen.  If it could also show on the wallpaper,  that will be better. Then every time I use my iPhone, I would be noticed by my goal.

I know nothing about the `iOS` development, but I'm wondering if there is an app could do this or could this be possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to display interactive elements on the lockscreen or wallpaper with a non jailbroken iPhone.

I would recommend [Countdown Widget](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/countdown-widget-keep-track/id917514700?mt=8) it's free an you can display countdowns in the notification center which you can also access from your lockscreen.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation~! Although it still can't display on the lock screen, I love this little widget and it's really helpful comparing to the tens of countdown apps I've tried in the store. PS: I think it's too difficult to find the most suitable one from the millions of apps in the apple store.

Answer (score 1):

A today extension would be the most fitting solution.

Also you could do something on the lock screen with local notifications queued up to fire at regular intervals showing the latest countdown value.

Comment: Although I don't know iOS development, the second approach sounds horrible.

Comment: You didn't say it needed to be nice ;) it certainly wouldn't be an elegant approach but it could be an option for a long term countdown. Pop up a notification every morning showing the latest countdown.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could figure out the exacting amount of hours and minutes and have that displayed by puttin it into the timer app that already exist in every iphone :)